# "Save as PDF" should be an option by default in Chrome (by Protractor)

Tags: pdf, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor, chrome-options

If I create Chrome shortcut with the Traget ***"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --print-to-pdf***  it opens Chrome with "Save as PDF" option by default. That's fine.

But if I try to do it using Protractor config options:

```
'chromeOptions': {
        args: ['--print-to-pdf'],
        prefs: {
            credentials_enable_service: false,
            download: {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'directory_upgrade': true,
                'default_directory': __dirname.replace('config', 'target\\downloads')
            }
        }
    }
```

I still have "real" Print option by default.

Do I do something wrong? Any other ways how to make option "Save as PDF" as default? Thanx.

Comment: do you have any idea how to do it using selenium ?